`changes` package and font?
I'm in a situation that I have to show changes from the previous version of my document. For that I use the changes package, but the delete{} command cannot break lines within a bracketed text and I don't know how to preserve font specification without using brackets:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\textwidth=0.5\textwidth
\begin{document}
\noindent
foo foo foo foo foo foo
\deleted{blah blah blah
  \emph{emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis} % no linebreak
  blah blah blah blah blah}
foo foo foo foo foo foo
\deleted{blah blah blah
  {\itshape emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis} % no linebreak
  blah blah blah blah blah}
foo foo foo foo foo foo
\deleted{blah blah blah
  \itshape emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis emphasis\normalfont
  blah blah blah blah blah}
\end{document}

I heard that the \delete{} cannot break lines within bracketed text. The above example confirms that.  Then, without brackets, the font-changing command changes the font only for the next word!
If this is the only way, I would have to insert \itshape before each word . . . .
